# Why is there overlap between a Flutter CupertinoApp's header and slivers underneath unless I wrap it in a Material widget?

Tags: ios, flutter

This seems like a bug, but I wanted to solicit feedback first. In my simple demo app below, you can see where the SliverChildBuilderDelegate is generating Text widgets as the SliverList. When you scroll up the text widgets overlap with the header. If you wrap the Text widget in a Material widget then that solves the problem (perhaps it's because of Material's clipping capability?). Mixing Material and Cupertino widgets isn't the best, however, particularly if you want to use a CupertinoTheme.

Any suggestions about what's going on and what to do about it is appreciated.

thanks

```
void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return CupertinoApp(
      title: 'Cupertino Demo',
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return CupertinoPageScaffold(
      child: SafeArea(
        child: CustomScrollView(
          shrinkWrap: true,
          slivers: [
            CupertinoSliverNavigationBar(
              largeTitle: Text('Cupertino Demo'),
            ),
            SliverList(
              delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate(
                (_, index) => Material(child: Text('This is list item number $index')),
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because of the shrinkWrap:true, you can read more here:
https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/28197

I don't see why would you need that, so simply just remove and it will work.